# Fallback method is not being called when rest call is failed by using feign client

Tags: microservices, netflix-eureka, netflix-feign, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I am trying to implement fallback by using Feign client but not getting success.Its a simplest code Please find below.

Main Class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@RestController
@EnableFeignClients
public class EurekaClient1Application {

    @Autowired
    public DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaClient1Application.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired 
    FeingInterface feingInterface;




    @GetMapping("/hi/{name}")
    public String test(@PathVariable String name)
    {
        String h = feingInterface.test(name);

        return h;
    }
}
```

Feign interface

```
@FeignClient(name="client22",fallback=FallBack.class)
public interface FeingInterface {

    @GetMapping("/hiname/{name}")
    public String test(@PathVariable("name") String name);

}
```

fallback class

```
@Component
class FallBack implements FeingInterface{

    @Override
    public String test(String name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "fall back methord being called";
    }

}
```

Getting Error in rest client but not from fallback method

> "timestamp": 1501950134118,
>       "status": 500,
>       "error": "Internal Server Error",
>       "exception": "java.lang.RuntimeException",
>       "message": "com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: client22",

To get the fallback method message I passed client22 eureka id which is not there in eureka server. I have stater-feign in pom. Can someone look into this.

Comment: I found one git issue related to this which basically say "@FeignClient annotated interface with fallback bean can not be autowired because it is not a unique bean" and this issue is being closed , now @FeignClient is now a primary bean(https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/899). But in this case what I am missing not finding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fallbacks are actually not handled by Feign itself, but by a circuit breaker. So, you need to put Hystrix (which is the Netflix circuit breaker) on your classpath and enable it in your application.yml file like this:

```
feign:
  hystrix:
    enabled: true
```

If you're using 'cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign' in your build.gradle or pom.xml file, Hystrix should be automatically on your classpath.

Comment: Please add explanation of your solution (how it's connected to question)